# Selenium Webdriver Java: Setting date on date-picker. Year is not populating in date-picker

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

I am automating a signup form for web application and there is a date of birth field which has date-picker on it. I am sending values in it by using sendKeys and the problem is that Year is not populating while day and month are populating successfully. I have tried changing date formats (like dd-mm-yyyy,mm-dd-yyyy etc) but still no use. Please check my code given below:

```
{
driver.findElement(By.id("customField2")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("customField2")).sendKeys("17072017");
}
```

Comment: Can you manually enter the same value for date of birth? There may be an allowed age range that is blocking the year value of 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried changing formats different ways to enter the dates and nothing I did solve my problem, I remembered that the date picker is a JS widget, so I looked up a way to use Javascript with Selenium.

I think that the Selenium methods weren't able to work with the Javascript in the date picker so the values I was entering didn't work correctly. When I changed to use the Selenium Javascript Executor, I didn't have that problem.

This is the code I found that works for the date picker.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;      
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('customField2').value='2018-07-17'");
```

Comment: If you could expand on your answer to explain why you think you needed to go to the JavascriptExecutor, then mark this as accepted, that would be good. I can think of a few reasons why you would need this, but without that information, your question and answer won't be as helpful as they could be.

Comment: Also note this is not replicating user action, and wouldn't necessarily trigger any JS behavior attached to the field.

Comment: @KatePaulk could you please explain reasons for using this? I tried changing formats and everything but nothing solved my problem, so I just looked over and found this code which solved it. I think the main reason to use this is that datepicker is in JS so you need a JS interface to execute JS in selenium. Your help will be appreciated as I am just a beginner in automation. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your answer to include the information from your comment. Feel free to edit if I misread what you were saying.

Comment: @KatePaulk thanks! that's exactly what I did!